# Watchkit: how to reload pages in a modal interface?

Tags: watchkit

Reloading the pages at a root level in watchkit is easy, just call

```
[WKInterfaceController reloadRootControllersWithNames:names contexts:contexts];
```

But what if I need to reload the pages when they are currently displayed modally?

For example after calling:

```
[self presentControllerWithNames:names contexts:contexts];
```

I don't think there's a way to reload the presented pages, or am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's not possible to reload pages in modal interface, you need to hide it and display it again.

Answer (score 1):

This might help you, when you are using a page based navigation on watchkit all the pages are loaded before starting. And when the user scrolls to a page you can do last minute updates from the method "willActivate".

Once displayed, a page cannot be reloaded... If you want to update its content just do it manually or hide/show new features.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no reload for pages fixed modally.

It can be fixed by saving the content to be updated in user defaults or singleton class etc.

The init/awakeWithContext passes the contexts to all page interface initially. When the the interface is presented on scrolling, willActivate is called. Here update the context for the interface from the saved data.